# Execute WITH RECURSIVE using sails-postgresql

Tags: postgresql, recursion, sails.js

I'm using a Sails server with sails-postgresql (0.11.4) database connector.

Trying to execute a WITH RECURSIVE query  as:

this.query({
 text:

```
WITH RECURSIVE recursetree(name, parent) AS (
SELECT name, parent
FROM data_indicators

UNION ALL
  SELECT t.name, t.parent
  FROM data_indicators t, recursetree rt 
  WHERE rt.name = t.parent
);
SELECT * FROM recursetree`
}, (err, res) => {

  ....
```

I get a error about the ";" but the query fails also with just the WITH  statement

It's really possible execute this kind of queries using sails-postgresql. Exists a best way?

Regards

Comment: I tried to restore your formatting, but I don't understand the intention of the backticks and extra `});` characters.

Comment: I removed the management of the query answer

 if (err) {console.log(err);return reject(err);}
        return resolve({
          registers: res.rows.length,
          data: res.rows,
          offset: reqParams.skip
        });
      });

'resolve' means that before exists a 'Promise' and 'offset' means exist a parameter 'skip', etc, etc and that was no rellevant in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With clauses (or common table expressions (CTEs) to give them their proper name) do not want the trailing semi-colon in Postgres.

```
with
    cte_name as(
        select * from foo
    )
select * from cte_name
```

So, remove your trailing semi-colon after your CTE and you should be good to go.